# Can I connect a LED cinema display to an iMac late 2013?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, displayport, cinema-display

I'm wondering if I can connect:

- [LED Cinema Display (27-inch)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP597?viewlocale=en_US&locale=it_IT)

to a:

- [iMac (27-inch, Late 2013)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP688?viewlocale=en_US&locale=it_IT)

My conundrum arises because the iMac has only thunderbolt ports but LED Cinema Display uses a miniDisplayPort connector. The port shape is identical but I'm wondering if the connection works.

[Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201736#:%7E:text=Information%20about%20these%20and%20other,check%20your%20Mac%20user%20guide.) Apple says:

> Thunderbolt and Thunderbolt 2 are not the same as Mini DisplayPort .
> They have the same shape, but use different symbols on the cable and
> port. However, this port does support Mini DisplayPort for video
> output, so you can use a Mini DisplayPort cable to connect a Mini
> DisplayPort display.

... but I'd like to doble check if somebody has already made this setup work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mini displayPort port on the Mac working as video output port when connected to a display with a  mini displayPort input. This monitor has the same maximum resolution as the internal display of the Mac. This means Mac supports the maximum resolution of Monitor.

When connecting monitor to your Mac, thunderbolt will not be used. The Mac has the ability to determine if the mini displayPort is being used for video or being used for thunderbolt data transfers.

Comment: Thanx David. So thunderbolt can output a video signal to a Mini DisplayPort cable and it should work fine. Right?

Comment: The port can works either in video output mode or thunderbolt mode. In the case, the Mac would automatically switch to video output mode.

Answer (score 1):

I connect a 13” touchbar macbook pro with usb-c ports to my 27” apple display with apple adaptors and also my 15” macbook pro to the same display with suitable apple adaptors.

Works fine.